# Android Game Development - Custom map leading to different activities

Tags: android

I'd like to create a custom map. It should be or look like one picture, but according to the part of which the user clicks, it should move the user to a different location (i.e. start a different activity). I've seen it done in several games but I don't know how to do it myself.

The part of the picture should have non-geometrical borders (obviously it would be easily done with many square images). Sadly, I don't even know what term describes what I want to do so I wasn't able to find any helpful tutorials or discussed topics.

Example:
Picture: http://i236.photobucket.com/albums/ff40/iathen/mapEx.png

- If the user touches the purple slide, (s)he should be leaded to activity_1
- If the user touches the blue slide, (s)he should be leaded to activity_2
- If the user touches the green slide, (s)he should be leaded to activity_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience there are 2 main (most used) ways to achieve this.

The first (my favorite):
**Get the data from a PNG**

You should write multiple layers to a canvas. These layers constitute your "zones" (blue, green, purple in the image). To obtain the data of these areas, you get it from PNGs (with transparencies off course) to write the canvas with whatever you want. You must store the values where there can be a tap from the user (non-transparent areas). Notice that this values can be scaled up/down depending on the map size, screen resolution, map dimensions, etc.

Once you've written the layers to the canvas you should check for a match of the user tap and the stored areas you have. You should take into consideration here the order in which the user tap is processed in your code. For instance, in your image, the purple layer is on top so it must be processed first, the blue as second, and the green as the last one. This way you can have an "island" inside a bigger area.

The second way:
**Generate the boundaries programmaticaly**

I think this solution is self-explanatory. The only I've faced with this variant is that when the surfaces boundaries get messy, it's really complicated to generate the proper equations.

**EDIT:**
Using the first approach you can employ multiple PNGs to load data or use a single PNG with data coded into the bytes (i.e. RGB values). It's up to you to decide which one to implement.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since a touchscreen itself isn't very accurate, your collision detection for the buttons doesn't need to be either. It would be a waste of time to try to make a complicated collision detection algorithm to detect a touch within those weird shapes.

Since you are making a game, I assume you know how to handle custom touch events, as well as canvas (at least). There are many ways to do what you want, but in the specific example image you linked is kind of a special case.

You could create a giant bounding circle around the three blobs, and then check if the user touched within the bounds of the circle (ie check if the distance from the touch to the center of the circle is less than or equal to the radius). Once you determine that it is, you could check which section of the circle it falls into by splitting it up into 3 equal sections. Requires some math, but shouldn't be that complicated.

It wouldn't be a perfect solution, but it should be good enough. Although, you might have to change the buttons a little so they aren't so stretched out horizontally, otherwise a bounding circle wouldn't be ideal.

Personally, in my games I always have "nodes" that represent the visual elements of the game, such as buttons. Instead of using a large image like you are doing, I would create separate images for each button, and then check their collisions with touch events independently. That way I could have each button check with their own individual bounding circles, or, if absolutely necessary, I could even have custom algorithms for each individual button.

These aren't perfect solutions. If you do want a pixel-perfect solution, you'll need to implement some polygon collision detection algorithms

One thing to consider is screen size and ratio. The only constants you should use are for percentages.